# PHP file permissions - creating a file

Tags: php, css, file, permissions

I'm in the process of creating a slideshow Wordpress plugin (although this isn't really a Wordpress question). Through all its various settings, it creates a CSS file through PHP that is used to style the slideshow.

The CSS file is created from all the different styling variables the user has saved to the database and hence the need to dynamically create one.

Problem is that some hosting companies (or shared hosting) cause problems when the PHP tries to save the created file. Generally these are file permission issues. Stopping this file from saving results in the slideshow not appearing correctly and malfunctioning.

Is there anything I can do through PHP as an alternative for users with such file permission issues? As far as I am aware you can modify file permissions and file ownership through PHP but I've personally never done it before and wouldn't really be sure about the right way to go about it yet cover as many different scenarios as possible.

For a lot of users it is simply a case of informing them on how to change the appropriate file permissions, but for the odd few this is completely beyond them and it's not possible for me to log into there FTP and do it for them (often because they wouldn't even know what FTP is).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You would need to look up [chmod()](http://www.php.net/chmod) to change your file permissions setting. It is possible that you are creating it at a level that is too low for anyone to access and may need to increase the availability.

Comment: Can't you write the file to the uploads dir or something? Some place where the permissions should already be set in a WP installation?

Comment: @Duniyadnd - A majority of the time the users have no issues, but occasionally some do. These hosts that stop the file from being created generally also block the chmod() function. Wondering if there is another step I can take for users with whom this function isn't an option.

Comment: @Madmartigan - Some hosting providers don't use the usual permissions: 755 for folders and 644 for single files. Wordpress recommends these permissions, but as far as I'm aware works if they are set differently. If the permissions are too low, the file I'm trying to create won't get created, and as such the plugin will get a file doesn't exist error when trying to load its stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could have a directory in which you would hold your css file(s) and chmod it to 777 like this in php:

```
<?php 
    chmod(dirname(__FILE__) . '/stylesheets', 0777); 
?>
```

The only problem I see here, that a company which denies you access to chmod your files is not that stupid to leave your php that permission... So, why don't you just have a kind of 'gateway'-file which will dynamically grab css values from DB, form a valid css output and serve it to the user?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you mean a PHP acting as a  dynamic CSS file? I looked into this, but would require loading the Wordpress functionality into the PHP file which isn't a great idea (so I've read).

Comment: Yup I meant a dynamic php css file. what u mean by saying - load wp functionality into php file?

Comment: Well to access the wordpress database values is easiest via Wordpress functionality, which would require loading Wordpress files which is turn causes a lot of extra server load, etc.

Comment: wp is anyway loaded if your plugin is... and you're the one who told that your script uses DB right? :) besides that you can grab constants from wp-config.php and connect to WP within your own php-mysql functions, but that will be more load to backend than using already loaded wp class, you can just declare a global $wpdb inside your plugin's function and query within it. Anyway it's up to you to decide how to access the database. It won't be so hard to grab a couple of values anyway, it won't be boring and long as connecting with tags or categories manually, i guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet may be:

```
// Get your values however
$css_values = $database->get_css_values();

// Generate your CSS stylesheet string
$css_string = css_values_to_string($css_values);

// Dump it directly
header('Content-type: text/css');
echo $css_string;
```

And point to the PHP file as a stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/generator.php" />
```

While this foregoes the "caching" functionality of dumping to a CSS file, surely you could leverage whatever caching support is available through Wordpress. Likely though, this approach of dynamically generating it every time will not result in bottlenecking (*profile anyway, if you're concerned*)

Comment: Are these custom functions you're using to get the values?

Comment: @MatthewRuddy -- Yes; substitute your functions/functionality for them. Essentially, do whatever you need to do in order to build the CSS file. Instead of storing it to a file and having the templates target it, the templates target your PHP script as a CSS resource, which, again instead of dumping the CSS data to a file, outputs it. As I mentioned, this negates the inherent caching functionality of dumping it to a file, however you get around any file system access issues this way.